# why are agents "jumping" to their attractor (other random position) when reaching a rectangular node?

Tags: anylogic

Probably a simple one: I have a network with rectangular nodes, connected by paths. When moving the agents from one rectangular node to another (moveTo), they follow a smooth motion along the path until reaching the edge of the rectangular node. Once reaching the edge of the rectangular node the agents "jump" to the corresponding (attractor or random position) within the node.

My intent is that the agents move smoothly from their origin along the path to the destination within the rectangular node. How do I achieve this?

Whether or not the agents move smoothly does not make a difference to the logic of course, but it is confusing when observing it for validation. Thank you.

Comment: in general the agents move smoothly and don't jump... so you will need to show more...

Comment: Hi Felipe thank you for your answer, I will assume the Benjamin's answer below is correct. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using paths and nodes is just an approximation to animate agents, it is not actual (physical) movement in space. These are helpers designed to easily animate processes visually.

If you need actual physical movement in space, use the pedestrian, car or material-handling library (depending on what is moving).

Note, though: These require substaintially more computational power as actual physical space is applied, so be careful and follow good modelling practice: only use what you really need for your model purpose.

PS: If you want to stay with your current setup: just stick to `PointNode`s on between your paths: no more jumping (but now agents can be "on top" of each other as ... again: no spatial system is applied)